# jQuery Event.Target for caller's reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, delegation

I don't know if I have forgotten how to do so or if it's a bug, but I just can't find the caller's reference in the "click" event using jQuery.

I'm doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#parent a.item').click(doSomething);
});

function doSomething(e) {
    // Alerts for demostrational purposes only
    alert(e.target);
    alert(e.currentTarget);
    alert(this);
    alert($(this)[0]);
}
```

All the alerts show the hyperlink´s href attribute(page URL + '#').
Am I doing something wrong?

**Notes:**
Using jQuery 1.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're alerting so you're seeing the string representation (since `alert()` takes a string)...which for an anchor is the `href`.  You could do this for example:

```
alert(e.target); //or perhaps alert(this.target); - alerts the href
alert(e.target.innerHTML);  //or perhaps alert(this.innerHTML); - alerts the html
```

[You can try it out/play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XfezX/), note that `this` and `e.target` aren't always the same, if the click came from a child element, they'll be different.

Comment: Well, I see that´s been working... but still, what I was originally trying to do was the following: $(e.target).closest('dl'), wich is still failing.